# Which Request Dialog is Which?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog, request

Screenshot: Facebook Request Dialogs

[image: screenshot]

http://jeremytani.artstooge.com/fb/stackoverflow/fb_requests.jpg

I'm trying to get a multi friend selector that is similar to what Zuma Blitz is using for inviting friends (left), but the multi-friend-selector that I got to pop up appears differently (right). What should I be searching for? The new Graph docs don't seem to have any examples of the Zuma version...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zuma Blitz is using the [FBML multi friend selector dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/).  You are using the [requests dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).  The FBML one they are using is deprecated though so I wouldn't recommend using it for a new application.